# ActiveRecord sorting with has_and_belongs_to_many with context

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We want to implement a user-based favourites sorting for a table, but we are struggling with the join.

### Our schema:

User ->* artice_user_favorites *<- Article

- Article A
- Article B
- Article C
- User A
- User B
- User A favourites A,C
- User B favourites A,B

### Our use case:

- Article table: Sorting by user favourites
- Favourites of the current user first
- Favourites of the current user last

### Expected:

Favourite articles of User A first

- Article A
- Article C
- Article B

We have found some examples where it was grouped by and counted the related objects, but it always included the favourite objects also from the other users.

[image: Expected list]

Comment: It's unclear what the goal is. You want a query that returns only one user's favorited articles, sorted by the article name?

Comment: @supremebeing7 No we want to have a list of all articles, but the favourited article of the current user should come first in the list.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of our expected result. Important is that the favourite column is based on the currently logged in user.